# how to pipe output from git commands into unix diff utility?

Tags: git, diff

I am trying to achieve something along the lines of

`` diff -ywB --suppress-common-lines `git branch --merged prod-server` `git branch --merged test-server` ``

so that I can know the difference of what has been merged into my test server branch but not in my production server branch

But when I execute the command above my exit status is 2 (indicates error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) on bash:

```
diff -ywB --suppress-common-lines <(git branch --merged prod-server) <(git branch --merged test-server)
```